# Searching model based on relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Topic model that belongs_to a Trip. The Trip has a start_date and end_date.
I want to find Topics based on the Trips date. How would I set up this query in rails?

```
Topic.joins(:trip).where('trip.start_date > ?', Time.now)
```

this throws the following error.

```
  Topic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "trips" ON "trips"."id" = 
"topics"."trip_id" WHERE (trip.start_date < '2014-10-22 13:17:37.764743') ORDER BY created_at DESC
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: trip.start_date: SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN     
"trips" ON "trips"."id" = "topics"."trip_id" WHERE (trip.start_date < '2014-10-22 13:17:37.764743')     
ORDER BY created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: trip.start_date: SELECT 
"topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "trips" ON "trips"."id" = "topics"."trip_id" WHERE 
(trip.start_date < '2014-10-22 13:17:37.764743')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

How am I structuring this query wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names in Rails are by convention plural (contrary to model names) and it's the case here, according to the log. So it should be:

```
Topic.joins(:trip).where('trips.start_date > ?', Time.now)
```